# WPF Caliburn Micro Conductors with Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem, caliburn.micro

I'm currently using Caliburn Micro 2.0.2 trying to use Menu at the top of my ShellView for Conductor navigation. The first level of MenuItem works fine but the second level throws "No target found for method Select." exception.

ShellView code:

```
<Grid  xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    xmlns:cal2="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
      <Menu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
          <Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" 
                  Value="[Event Click] = [Action Select($DataContext)]" />
          <Setter Property="cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext" 
                  Value="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}}"/>
        </Style>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                                   DataType="{x:Type cal2:Screen}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </Menu.Resources>
    </Menu>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" cal:View.Model="{Binding ActiveItem}"/>
  </Grid>
```

ShellViewModel code:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
  public ShellViewModel(IEnumerable<IScreen> viewmodels)
  {
  //omitted for brevity. 
  }
  public void Select(object datacontext)
  {
      var vm = datacontext as IScreen;
      if (vm != null && Items.Contains(vm))
      {
        ActivateItem(vm);
      }
   }
 }
```

The inner Conductors that have more view models have the same select method with the corresponding interface type. I can't figure out how to get the event to hookup. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. The binding to RelativeSource Self was the problem. I have now have the binding to the Element by Name. This also allows me to just have the one method on the shell.

ShellView code:

```
<Grid  xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    xmlns:cal2="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu x:Name="menu" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <Menu.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
      <Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" 
              Value="[Event Click] = [Action Select($DataContext)]" />
      <Setter Property="cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext" 
              Value="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=menu}"/>
    </Style>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                               DataType="{x:Type cal2:Screen}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </Menu.Resources>
 </Menu>        
 <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" cal:View.Model="{Binding ActiveItem}"/>
</Grid>
```

ShellViewModel code:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
  public ShellViewModel(IEnumerable<IScreen> viewmodels)
  {
  //omitted for brevity. 
  }
  public void Select(object datacontext)
  {
      var vm = datacontext as IScreen;
      if (vm != null && Items.Contains(vm))
      {
         if (vm.IsActive)
           return;
         ActivateItem(vm);
         vm.Refresh();
      }
      else
      {
         var vm2 = datacontext as Screen;
         if (vm2 != null)
         {
           (vm2.Parent as IConductActiveItem)?.ActivateItem(vm2);
            vm2.Refresh();
         }
      }
   }       
 }
```